# How to get ID from insert()

Tags: android, sqlite

I've got a little problem with retrieving ID from added row.
`insertWithConflict` inside my `ContentProvider` returns the ID of freshly added row but I don't know a way to get it from my `ContentProvider` to my `IntentService` responsible for firing insert.

**CODE**

**Insert in `IntentService`**

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse(MicroDatabaseProvider.CONTENT_URI + "/" +  MicroDatabaseProvider.ORGANIZER_SEARCH_IN);
getContentResolver().insert(uri, cv);
```

**Insert in `ContetnProvider`**

```
long idLong = sqlDB.insertWithOnConflict(DbHelperMicro.ORGANIZER_SEARCH_TABLE,
                    null,
                    values,
                    SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_IGNORE);
            getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(Uri.parse(CONTENT_URI + "/" + ORGANIZER_SEARCH_QUE), null);
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your `insert` function in your `ContentProvider`should return an `Uri` value like the following:

```
public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues values) {
//...
return Uri.parse(base_uri+ "/" + id); //where base uri is the base uri from your table
}
```

If it is like I have shown you, you can retreive the id from that URI.

Use the following code in your `IntentService`

```
Uri result = getContentResolver().insert(uri, cv); 

long id = Long.parseLong(uri.getLastPathSegment());
```

Comment: I did that and the URI was `microdatabase/0`, which I know is false because at the same time I logged my `idLong` and it was 34.

Comment: Show then your return statement in your  `ContentProvider`

Comment: OH MY I AM SO DENSE .......
`return Uri.parse(BASE_PATH + "/" + id);`
it should be `idLong`

Comment: Thanks for help, will mark as solved as soon as I can.

Comment: `getLastPathSegment()` returning `String`